# How can I insert many blobs with sqlite3 C API?

Tags: c, sqlite, blob

Here is the schema of the table I'm working with

```
CREATE TABLE clauses(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content BLOB)
```

I want to insert a huge number of records in that table. I was thinking of something like

```
void insert_records(sqlite3* db) {
    int clause[CLAUSE_SIZE];
    char sql[] = "INSERT INTO clauses(content) VALUES(?)";
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt = NULL;

    if (sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in prepare : %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, clause, sizeof(clause), SQLITE_STATIC) != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in bind : %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nb_clauses ; i++) {
       gen_clause(clause);

       if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
           fprintf(stderr, "error in step : %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
           exit(1);
       }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
 }
```

but that does not work : only the first item is inserted and, on the second iteration, the program dies with "error in step : unknown error".

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call [sqlite3_reset](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) before you can re-execute the prepared statement.